# Google RPC uncatchable exception on Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, google-api-client, grpc

I'm using the Google OCR API (with varying degrees of success) in an application. When I run my code in its Windows Azure Webapp the OCR call fails kicking me me all the way out of the web request with a GrpcException. This occurs on calling:

```
ImageAnnotatorClient.DetectText(image);
```

I'm unable to catch the exception at all. The only signal that I came from the google lib is in the output.

Has anyone had a similar experience with any of the google .net wrapper calls?

Comment: Do you try to use [remote debugging feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) to find the code snippet that cause the error?

Comment: Yes, I've connected to the Azure web app and attempted to catch the exception. It logs the exception type but won't stop on a breakpoint in a catch clause or even let me step over/out from the problematic method.